# How to hide the MPmoviePlayerController's control bar

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

How to hide the MPmoviePlayerController's  control bar.

I just want to make the movie get a  fullscreen  and have nothing on it.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dataPath ofType:@""]];
        moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:moviePlayerController];  

        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
        [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
        if ([moviePlayerController respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsAirPlay:)])    
            //Allow airplay ifavailabe
        [moviePlayerController setAllowsAirPlay:YES];

        [moviePlayerController play];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Comment: if i want to hide only bottom bar controller then??